# TFS 2010 build NUnit inconclusive test considered as failed

Tags: tfs, nunit

I'm running gated check in builds for TFS 2010 with NUnit test and I have seen that tests with ignore make the build fail although there are no errors in the TFS log. I have followed this blog post to configure my TFS http://blog.ianbattersby.com/2012/01/04/tfsbuild-2010-nunit-integration/

The problem seems that tests decorated with [Ignore] appears in nunit xml log as inconclusive and therefore have a failed status.

The workaround is not to use ignore and simply comment those tests, but it a bit odd solution to me.

Any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: How inconclusive tests looks like in your xml output — can you provide any example?

Comment: Thoough it was this kind of results `<test-suite type="TestFixture" name="SaveUploadFileServiceTest" executed="True" result="Inconclusive" success="False" time="0.001" asserts="0" />` but I hacked NUnit to mark inclonclusive test as Success but still not working. There are no errors on TFS logs but Build is partially failed